# Best way to suppress mypy's "has no attribute" for global variable that is initialized later

Tags: python, mypy, linter

I have read other questions on this topic - and all of them are about another level (classes, methods or function).
I'm trying to find a way to suppress "has not attribute" message from mypy for a **module level** name.

Code looks like this

```
service: Service | None = None

@on_startup
def init():
    global service
    inject.configure(config)
    service = get_service()
```

So I am 100% sure that service will be not `None` whenever I will access it. The only way I see now is to mark each line with `service.*` as `# type: ignore`. It leads to huge amount of comments. Is there any other way to let this code pass mypy?

Error message is: `Item "None" of "Optional[Service]" has no attribute "..."`

Comment: What error message do you get exactly?

Comment: My guess is that you get errors at *other places* in the code where `service` is used? If your intention is that `service` *always* is a `Service` instance you should write `service: Service`, not `service: Service | None = None`. I'm sure this has already been answered somewhere, but I can't find it now.

Comment: I can't declare `service` on a module level without any value, and I cannot call `get_service` before `inject.configure`, and I cannot call `inject.configure` on a module level, so it will be called each time this module is imported.

Comment: "I can't declare `service` on a module level without any value" - why not? Syntactically, `service: Service` is perfectly valid. Does your `inject.configure` thing not work if you do that?

Comment: I tried that, but in this case I should always say `global service`, otherwise pylama and flake8 say `undefined name`

Comment: If you are 100% sure that your `service` is never `None`, annotate it as `Service`. If you have any reason to assign None initially to satisfy other tools, do it: `service: Service = None  # type: ignore`. It's the only ignore place, and you won't have to constantly check whether this variable is not None.

Comment: @SUTerliakov that's best solution for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an explicit guard will tell MyPy that you handle this case, and thus get rid of the warning.

```
assert service is not None
```

before you access the variable is sufficient, though for robustness, you might want to put in a proper

```
    try:
        ... # access service.attribute
    except AttributeError:
        raise Hell()
```

which performs an explicit check even when assertions are disabled.